# LWC Object.assign dot notation throwing error - need to use name field in datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, wire

I am using a datatable in a custom listview LWC component and need to display the lookup fields as urls. I'm trying to flatten the results in order to use the dot notation for a lookup on the Account object, but the js is throwing an error when it gets to the Object.assign statement.

My apex query:

```
List<Related_Account__c> relaccs = [SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Account__r.Name
    FROM Related_Account__c
  ];
```

My LWC .js:

```
const COLS = [
  {
    label: "Name",
    fieldName: "nameUrl",
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" }, target: "_blank" },
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    label: "Account",
    fieldName: "accountUrl",
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: {
      label: { fieldName: "accountName" },
      target: "_blank"
    }
  }]

..........

@wire(getRelatedAccounts)
  relatedaccountsWire(result) {
    this.wiredRelatedAccounts = result;
    if (result.data) {
      this.relatedaccounts = result.data.map((row) =>
        Object.assign(
          {
            nameUrl: "/" + row.Id,
            accountUrl: "/" + row.Account__c,
            accountName: row.Account__r.Name
          },
          row
        )
      );
      this.baseData = [...this.relatedaccounts];
    }
    if (result.error) {
      console.error(result.error);
    }
  }
```

[image]

It throws this error immediately after getting to the Name assignment:
[image]

Why does this not work and what can I do to make it work (other than creating a wrapper object on the apex side)? I thought this was a neat way to do it, but looks like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Account__c` is null, `Account__r` will be undefined. For a quick fix, just use the safe navigation operator `?.`:

```
accountName: row.Account__r?.Name
```

Comment: Brilliant :). How can I prevent it populating the datatable field with '/undefined' when the lookup is null, which is what it's doing now that I made the change you suggested?

Comment: @Irene `accountName: row.Account__r?.Name ?? 'Some other value'` The `??` operator returns the right-hand side if the left-hand side is null or undefined. You can use `''` (empty string) to avoid showing anything.

Comment: How do I prevent it creating the url field if the Account__c is blank? At the moment it's creating '.../undefined' with whatever I put into the alt text for the Account__r?.Name field. I obviously don't want it to create the url if there's no value.

Comment: @Irene You can use the ternary operator `?:`, as in ``accountUrl: row.Account__c? `/${row.Account__c}`:''`` Note that `\`` is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I've learned about new stuff - works like a dream, thanks.